# textarea auto-resize in jquery

Tags: jquery, textarea

How can I make a `<textarea>` auto-resize with its content (like in Facebook) using jQuery.

Comment: Auto-resize according to what? The containing element? The window? The length of the text?

Comment: I presume you mean like the default Safari/Chrome textarea... or the growing textarea like on Facebook?

Comment: just like face book
i want to resize my textbox when i enter more no of text in  the textbox

Comment: I don't have code (handy) that will do this, but IIRC, facebook has a hidden div, styled identical to the textarea that gets updated with whatever is typed.  The div is then measured to see how big it is, and then the textarea is resized to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/)

Check this demo: http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#textarea

Answer (score 2):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function adjustTextarea(this_){

    var value_ = this_.value;

    value_ = value_.replace(new RegExp("\n\r", 'gi'), "\n");
    value_ = value_.replace(new RegExp("\r", 'gi'), "\n");

    var split_ = value_.split("\n");
    this_.rows = split_.length;

    return;
    }

    </script>

    <textarea cols="100" style="overflow:hidden;" onkeyup="adjustTextarea(this);" onfocus="adjustTextarea(this);" >
    Text
    </textarea>
```

Comment: Great solution in pure javascript!

Answer (score 0):

Use James Padolsey autoResize jquery plugin from http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/

Basic usage

```
    $('textarea#comment').autoResize({
        // On resize:
        onResize : function() {
        $(this).css({opacity:0.8});
        },
        // After resize:
        animateCallback : function() {
        $(this).css({opacity:1});
        },
        // Quite slow animation:
        animateDuration : 300,
        // More extra space:
        extraSpace : 40
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Super light weight:

Has anyone considered contenteditable? No messing around with scrolling,a nd the only JS I like about it is if you plan on saving the data on blur... and apparently, it's compatible on all of the popular browsers : http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable

Just style it to look like a text box, and it autosizes... Make its min-height the preferred text height and have at it.

What's cool about this approach is that you can save  and  tags on some of the browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/gbutiri/v31o8xfo/

```
<style>
.autoheight {
    min-height: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Arial;
    line-height: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    resize: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    outline: none;
    width: 200px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('blur','.autoheight',function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    // The text is here. Do whatever you want with it.
    console.log($this.html());
});

</script>
<div class="autoheight contenteditable" contenteditable="true">Mickey <b>Mouse</b></div>
```