# TextBox Auto Expandable

Tags: jquery

how can i make textbox auto expandable when i insert the text

Comment: You should not keep asking the same or **very** related question, but ask one complete question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949051/textbox-auto-resize-in-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948230/auto-expand-textarea should be updated.

Comment: yaa nick is right
He should not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of [auto-expander](http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/expander.html) [plugins](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/) for JQuery.  You'll want to try one of those.